# Issues with VLookup and possible work around

Tags: vba, vlookup

this is my first post to stack however i've used it in my work for a couple of years. Its proven an invaluable reference for a VBA newbie like myself.
I have a large worksheet which is used for rostering and displaying staff working hours. I'm trying to use vlookup in the code below to generate the contact number and supplier detail of known operatives, so far thats easy however say a row has been populated with details for an operative who doesnt exist on the vlookup table (this is often the case) if i click on the detail after the fact or copy detail into the cell the vlookup will run and delete the maunally entered detail. Basically i want excel to run the vlookup only if theres a match and if it encounters an error to leave the manually inputted data alone.
here's what i have so far.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim RNG1 As Range
Dim RNG2 As Range
Dim RNG3 As Range

Set RNG1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A30") 'RANGES WHERE AN OPERATIVE NAME IS PLACED
Set RNG2 = Sheet1.Range("DQ:D30")
Set RNG3 = Sheet81.Range("G1:G30")

If Not Intersect(Target, Union(RNG1, RNG2, RNG3)) Is Nothing Then
    Set MyRange = Sheet1.Range("A2:C497") 'TABLE WHERE VLOOKUP DATA IS STORED ON SEPERATE SHEET

    Target.Offset(0, 2) = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(Target.Value, MyRange, 3, False), "")
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(Target.Value, MyRange, 2, False), "")
End If
Exit Sub
```

[image]

Comment: So you just need to check if the vlookup results in an error before inserting anything?

Comment: i believe so. I want the macro to leave the cell value intact if the vlookup would result in an N/A Error

Comment: What exactly is your difficulty - do the check first and then only enter the result if it's not an error?

Comment: my premise is to automate data population of known individuals (those stored on the table) The aim is that when a name is placed in a cell within RNG1-3 that excel will either recognise the data and populate the next 2 cells on the right, or If the name entered is unknown then i dont want the vlookup to run, leaving the next two cells on the right as they are.

Comment: Yes I understand what you're doing, just wondering what you were stuck with on the code as it's not hugely different from what you have already written.

Comment: Oh sorry for misunderstanding. to be honest i've taken the code i've got as far as i can go with it. I just cant seem to figure out the tweek that i need to make.

Comment: OK, I've suggested an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `Find` here as `Match` won't work on a multi-column range.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim RNG1 As Range
Dim RNG2 As Range
Dim RNG3 As Range
Dim r As Range

Set RNG1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A30") 'RANGES WHERE AN OPERATIVE NAME IS PLACED
Set RNG2 = Sheet1.Range("D1:D30")
Set RNG3 = Sheet81.Range("G1:G30")

If Not Intersect(Target, Union(RNG1, RNG2, RNG3)) Is Nothing Then
    Set MyRange = Sheet2.Range("A2:C497") 'TABLE WHERE VLOOKUP DATA IS STORED ON SEPERATE SHEET
    Set r = Union(RNG1, RNG2, RNG3).Find(what:=Target.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then   'name is found
        Target.Offset(0, 2) = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, MyRange, 3, False)
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, MyRange, 2, False)
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but when i click into a cell (Say A1) which includes an operative who's not on the known list  in order to edit it(Perhaps for spelling issues etc) the code runs and deletes the manually inputted data in cells B1 & C1

Comment: It's possible I used the wrong range, RNG1, to check. Btw it does seem strange that RNG1 is part of the latter range.

Comment: Hi again. Yeah i saw that your suggestion referenced RNG1 instead of 'MyRange' in the Match application. I corrected it but still no dice. Corrected code below

Comment: Match won't work in a multi-column range. Which cells contain the list of names you want to check against the changed cell?

Comment: in this case cells in row A,D & G would be where a name would be entered and then checked against cells A2:C500 on sheet 2

Comment: I think what confused me was that `myrange` is defined on the same sheet as the other ranges - presumably that is a typo?

Comment: Yes sorry SJR that was a typo on my part. I corrected it on the answer post i subsequently deleted. MyRange is on a seperate sheet. For this example say sheet2

Comment: Answer amended above.

Comment: Hi SJR, Firstly thank you for your help so far. But i'm afraid i'm not getting the results i'm after. Its most likely down to me communicating poorly.

Comment: I've attached an example document with your revised code and included details for operatives MR A - MR E. You'll see if you click on MR F's cell that the code runs and then deletes his data as hes not stored on sheet2. Thats what i want to avoid. hope this helps. Thanks again

Comment: Damn. How do you attach example files on Stack?

Comment: You can't, but you can post a screenshot. Nothing in my code deletes anything.

Comment: I've added a picture to your answer. Just waiting for it to be approved before its visible

Comment: I've added the picture to your original question.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint and then stepping through so that you can see what's going on when you make a change. I can't tell from that picture. I suppose you could link to a file on a reputable site such as dropbox. Just cut it down to the minimum necessary.

Comment: Great news. I've managed to crack the issue. R was set to the union ranges not the lookup table range. Now that i've changed that around the code runs with a known operative and leaves unknown ones alone. I can now take this example and expand it onto my master sheet. Thank you for your help on this on SJR!

Comment: Glad it works, perhaps you could accept the answer.